# Serializing Lazy members under DataContract

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have the following type of code:

```
[DataContract(Name ="test_class")]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember(Name = "test")]
    private Lazy<IList<AnotherClass>> lazyList;
}
```

And I would like to serialize it with the `DataContractSerializer` into `XML`. I want to save the value of the `Lazy`. How does one go about this?

Comment: Doesn't this kill the necessity for a Lazy member? You cannot use an inbetween dto for your usecase?